# How to deeply remove null values, empty objects and empty array from an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var myObject = { a: { b: [{}], c: [{}, {d: 2}], e: 2, f: {} }, g:{}, h:[], i: [null, 2] }
```

I want to remove null values and and empty objects (array and objects) so that it looks like:

```
{ a: {c: [ {d: 2} ], e: 2 }, i: [ 2 ] }
```

The function should remove null values, empty objects and empty arrays.  Any elegant way to do it ?

Comment: probably it is [a bad practice](https://jsfiddle.net/k4mor6gs/1/) uses regex.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. If the input object has `a.c` as an array, why isn't the non-empty array preserved, that is, `{ a: { c: [{ d: 2 }], e: 2}, i: [2] }`? Why does the `i` array of `[null, 2]` disappear and then appear cleaned as a property of `g`? Why are there two `c` properties in the output (nested), whereas there's only ever one `c` property in the input?

Comment: Running your code in your answer produces `{ a: { c: [{ d: 2 }], e: 2}, i: [2] }`, as expected from the *problem description*, so I'm assuming that the desired output posted in the question just has typos?

Comment: I suspect there is a very elegant answer using ES6 syntax that would be 3 or 4 lines long. Hoping someone delivers.

Comment: @EdmundReed I'm pretty sure any solution will require manual recursion, explicit testing of objects vs arrays vs primitives (and nulls), and explicit checking of the number of remaining truthy keys - which is too much to do in only a few lines. My answer uses 15 *short* lines, it could be condensed into fewer, but that would compromise readability, which matters a whole lot more than code length.

Comment: There was a typo in my desired output. I made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that clean the object recursively. It will loop deeply through all the properties and remove null values, null arrays and null objects:

```
cleanUpObject(jsonObject: object): object {

    Object.keys(jsonObject).forEach(function (key, index) {
        const currentObj = jsonObject[key]

        if (_.isNull(currentObj)) {
            delete jsonObject[key]
        } else if (_.isObject(currentObj)) {
            if (_.isArray(currentObj)) {
                if (!currentObj.length) {
                    delete jsonObject[key]
                } else {
                    const cleanupArrayObj = []
                    for (const obj of currentObj) {
                        if (!_.isNull(obj)) {
                            const cleanObj = this.cleanUpJson(obj)
                            if (!_.isEmpty(cleanObj)) {
                                cleanupArrayObj.push(cleanObj)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!cleanupArrayObj.length) {
                        delete jsonObject[key]
                    } else {
                        jsonObject[key] = cleanupArrayObj
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (_.isEmpty(Object.keys(jsonObject[key]))) {
                    delete jsonObject[key]
                } else {
                    jsonObject[key] = this.cleanUpJson(currentObj)

                    if (_.isEmpty(Object.keys(jsonObject[key]))) {
                        delete jsonObject[key]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, this)

    return jsonObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what you mean by *clean*, but from what I understand, you want to remove all null and empty values. This algorithm is straight-forward: *recursively check for and remove any empty / null values (which are recursively checked).*

```js
function clean(obj) {
  // clean array
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (let i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
      if (isNothing(obj[i])) obj.splice(i, 1);  // remove value if falsy
      else if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') clean(obj[i]); // recurse if it's a truthy object
    }
    
  // clean other object
  } else {
    for (let prop in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
      if (isNothing(obj[prop])) delete obj[prop]; // remove value if falsy
      else if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') clean(obj[prop]); // recurse if it's a truthy object
    }
  }
}

// Recursively check for populated or nonnull content. If none found, return `true`. Recursive so [{}] will be treated as empty.
function isNothing(item) {
  // null / undefined
  if (item == null) return true;
  
  // deep object falsiness
  if (typeof item === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      // array -> check for populated/nonnull value
      for (let i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
        if (!isNothing(item[i])) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    // other object -> check for populated/nonnull value
    for (let prop in item) {
      if (!item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
      if (!isNothing(item[prop])) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var myObject = { a: { b: [{}], c: [{}, {d: 2}], e: 2, f: {} }, g:{}, h:[], i: [null, 2] };

console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(myObject));
clean(myObject);
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Answer (score -1):

To reduce repetitive code, one option is to define a function (let's call it `itemToBool`) that can determine whether a generic value passed to it is truthy, or recursively truthy *somewhere*, should the value be an array or object. Then, in the function that gets passed the original object (or, gets recursively passed an object or array), you can call that `itemToBool` function whenever there's a value to validate.

In the case of arrays, `map` by `itemToBool` and then `filter` by Boolean. In the case of objects, `reduce` the `entries` of the object into another object: pass each value of the object through `itemToBool` to recursively transform it (in case the value is an array or object), and if the transformed value has any keys (or is a truthy primitive), assign it to the accumulator. No need to depend a library:

```js
var myObject = {
  a: {
    b: [{}],
    c: [{}, {
      d: 2
    }],
    e: 2,
    f: {}
  },
  g: {},
  h: [],
  i: [null, 2]
};

// Returns a falsey value if the item is falsey,
// or if the deep cleaned array or object is empty:
const itemToBool = item => {
  if (typeof item !== 'object' || item === null) return item;
  const cleanedItem = clean(item);
  return Object.keys(cleanedItem).length !== 0 && cleanedItem;
};

const clean = obj => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    const newArr = obj.map(itemToBool).filter(Boolean);
    return newArr.length && newArr;
  }
  const newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    const newVal = itemToBool(val);
    if (newVal) a[key] = newVal;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(newObj).length > 0 && newObj;
};

console.log(clean(myObject));
```

Hmm... you also might abstract the check of the number of keys into a function as well:

```js
var myObject={a:{b:[{}],c:[{},{d:2}],e:2,f:{}},g:{},h:[],i:[null,2]}

// Returns the object / array if it has at least one key, else returns false:
const validObj = obj => Object.keys(obj).length && obj;
const itemToBool = item => (
  typeof item !== 'object' || item === null
  ? item
  : validObj(clean(item))
);
const clean = obj => validObj(
  Array.isArray(obj)
  ? obj.map(itemToBool).filter(Boolean)
  : Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
      const newVal = itemToBool(val);
      if (newVal) a[key] = newVal;
      return a;
    }, {})
);

console.log(clean(myObject));
```