# Remove empty & null values from nested object (ES6) - Clean nested Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got an object which looks like this :

```
{
    "a": "string not empty",
    "b": {
        "c": "string not empty",       
    },
    "d": {
        "e": false,
        "f": 0,
        "g": true,
        "h": 10
    },
    "i": {
        "j": 0,
        "k": null
    },
    "l": {
        "m": null
    },
    "n": {
        "o": 1,
        "p": "string (not empty)",
        "q": {}
    },
    "r": [],
    "l": "2000-01-01T01:01:00.000Z",
}
```

Thanks to the code provided by here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38364486/3912805 I can now remove all `null` values of my nested object.

I used this function so far to `removeNull` :

```
removeNull = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
    (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && removeNull(obj[key]) ||
    (obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === null) && delete obj[key]
  );
  return obj;
};
```

But I would like to enhance this function to allow me to remove all empty arrays  or any empty collection which may exists in my nested object.

Final results should be *without* `k`, `l` & `m`, `q`, `r`, `l`:

```
{
    "a": "string not empty",
    "b": {
        "c": "string not empty",       
    },
    "d": {
        "e": false,
        "f": 0,
        "g": true,
        "h": 10
    },
    "i": {
        "j": 0
    },
    "n": {
        "o": 1,
        "p": "string (not empty)"
    },
    "l": "2000-01-01T01:01:00.000Z",
}
```

I need to keep all values which were set to `0` or to `false`.

I would like to enhance this `removeNull`'s method using ES6 method, but so far I failed to do it.

I also tried old school method which was used for this [How to deeply remove null values, empty objects and empty array from an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175209/how-to-deeply-remove-null-values-empty-objects-and-empty-array-from-an-object)

```
itemToBool = item => {
  if (typeof item !== 'object' || item === null) return item;
  const cleanedItem = cleanObject(item);
  return Object.keys(cleanedItem).length !== 0 && cleanedItem;
};

cleanObject = obj => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    const newArr = obj.map(itemToBool).filter(Boolean);
    return newArr.length && newArr;
  }
  const newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    const newVal = itemToBool(val);
    if (newVal !== null || newVal === false) a[key] = newVal;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(newObj).length > 0 && newObj;
};
```

but it fails too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Nina Scholz, my enhanced version will be :

```
cleanObject = function(object) {
    Object
        .entries(object)
        .forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object')
                cleanObject(v);
            if (v && 
                typeof v === 'object' && 
                !Object.keys(v).length || 
                v === null || 
                v === undefined ||
                v.length === 0
            ) {
                if (Array.isArray(object))
                    object.splice(k, 1);
                else if (!(v instanceof Date))
                    delete object[k];
            }
        });
    return object;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably `&& !(v instanceof Date)` could be placed before `&& !Object.keys(v).length` because entering inside if block for Date checking isn't needed - checking for Date can be done earlier

Answer (score 14):

You could take an straight forward approach by iterating the key/value pairs of the object and iterate nested iterable objects first and then delete the unwanted keys.

```js
function clean(object) {
    Object
        .entries(object)
        .forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
                clean(v);
            }
            if (v && typeof v === 'object' && !Object.keys(v).length || v === null || v === undefined) {
                if (Array.isArray(object)) {
                    object.splice(k, 1);
                } else {
                    delete object[k];
                }
            }
        });
    return object;
}

var object = { a: "string not empty", b: { c: "string not empty" }, d: { e: false, f: 0, g: true, h: 10 }, i: { j: 0, k: null }, l: { m: null }, n: { o: 1, p: "string (not empty)", q: {} }, r: [{ foo: null }] };

console.log(clean(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `delete object[k];`  should be `Array.isArray(object) ? object.splice(k, 1) : delete object[k];` e.g. `"r": []` was `"r": [{a:undefined}, {a:1}]`

Comment: I tried to debug a bit but if I have `r: "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"` in my nested object, it will be removed with your method

Comment: do you have an `Date` object? if string, it stays.

Comment: Seems it was a `Date` object after all. How can I avoid to remove them ?

Comment: I edited my exemple, so far I just added this to your solution :
`if (Array.isArray(object))
                    object.splice(k, 1);
                else if (!(v instanceof Date))
                    delete object[k];`

Answer (score 13):

You can exploit [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and it's optional second argument `replacer` but be aware the following code removes `null` *and* `undefined`.

```js
const sanitize = (obj) => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    return (value === null ? undefined : value);
  }));
};

const obj = {
  "a": "string not empty",
  "b": {
    "c": "string not empty",
  },
  "d": {
    "e": false,
    "f": 0,
    "g": true,
    "h": 10
  },
  "i": {
    "j": 0,
    "k": null
  },
  "l": {
    "m": null
  },
  "n": {
    "o": 1,
    "p": "string (not empty)",
    "q": {}
  },
  "r": [],
  "l": "2000-01-01T01:01:00.000Z",
}

console.log(sanitize(obj))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to mutate the object and need a new copy, then you can stringify the object to json and parse it, and filter at the time of parsing. If you don't need the source object then you can override the result into same reference. Its may not the performance efficient approach but obviously much cleaner and not a self recursive approach.

```js
var obj = {
    "a": "string not empty",
    "b": {
        "c": "string not empty",       
    },
    "d": {
        "e": false,
        "f": 0,
        "g": true,
        "h": 10
    },
    "i": {
        "j": 0,
        "k": null
    },
    "l": {
        "m": null
    },
    "n": {
        "o": 1,
        "p": "string (not empty)",
        "q": {}
    },
    "r": [],
    "s": {"t": null},
    "u": [null, {"v": {}}]
}
function copyNonEmpty(o) {
  let ignores = [null, undefined, ""],
    isNonEmpty = d => !ignores.includes(d) && (typeof(d) !== "object" || Object.keys(d).length)
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o), function(k, v) {
    if (isNonEmpty(v))
      return v;
  });
}

var res = copyNonEmpty(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

If value is `Object` or `Array` then `typeof` will return `object` and `Object.keys` will return a array of keys for both the cases (`"0", "1"`,`2`... in case of array), and the array length (of keys) will 0 if its an empty array or object. So, conditionally, it will must not (`null`, `undefined` or `""`) and (either a non `object/array` **OR** `object/array` which is non-empty and then you can take that value.

Answer (score 3):

To remove empty arrays, strings, null, undefined values

```
function removeEmptyElements(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach((element, index) => obj.splice(index, 1, removeEmptyElements(element)));
    return obj;
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([, v]) => (Array.isArray(v) ? v.length !== 0 : (v !== null && v !== '' && v !== undefined)))
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, v === (Object(v)) ? removeEmptyElements(v) : v]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have just solved the same issue, so I want to share with you guys. My code also clean nested object and array, can be customize depend on your requirement :

```js
cleanObject = (input) => {
  if (typeof input === 'object' && input !== null) {
    if(Array.isArray(input)) {
      return input.map(cleanObject)
                  .filter(item => item !== null && item !== undefined) 
    }

    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(input)
            .map(([key, val]) => [key, cleanObject(val)])
            .filter(([k, v]) => v !== null && v !== undefined)
    );

  } 

  return input;
}
// testcase:
 const testVal = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: undefined,
  d: { a: 99, b: null },
  e: { a: 1, b: 2, d: undefined, g: null, e: 0 },
  f: [1, 0, null, undefined],
  g: [1, 2],
  h: { aa: 1, bb: { c: 1, d: [111, null], e: 'hello' } },
};

cleanObject(testVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it by as follow

```js
   const test = {
       a: '',
       b: 1,
       c: [],
       d: {
        e: null,
        f: 0,
        g: undefined,
        h: {
            i: 'test',
            j: {},
            k: '',
            l: {
                m: 'yo test',
                n: 'go for it'
            }
        }
     },
    e: 'yo tested'
    };

    const JS_PRIMITIVE_TYPES = { 'string': 1, 'number': 1, 'undefined': 1, 'boolean': 1, 
    'symbol': 1 }

    const isValuePrimitiveType = (value) => {
    const typeOfVal = typeof value;
    if (JS_PRIMITIVE_TYPES.hasOwnProperty(typeOfVal)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }

    /* MAIN Function which runs and call other functions
       allKeys : keys of object Object.keys(test);
       badJson : json which needs to be update
    */
      const iterateObjForRemoveEmptyElem = (badJson, allKeys) => {
       for (let index = 0; index < allKeys.length; index++) {
          const key = allKeys[index];
          if (isEmpty(badJson[key])) {
             delete badJson[key];
          } else if (Array.isArray(badJson[key]) || isValuePrimitiveType(badJson[key])) {
            continue;
         }
         else {
            const newKeys = Object.keys(badJson[key]);
            const newJson = Object.assign({}, badJson[key]);
            badJson[key] = iterateObjForRemoveEmptyElem(newJson, newKeys);
        }
    }
    return badJson;
    }



    const isEmpty = (val) => {
     if(val === '' || val === null || val === undefined ) {
         return true;
     } else if (Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0){
        return true;
     } else if(typeof val === 'object' && Object.keys(val).length === 0){
        return true;
     }
    return false;
    }

    const myKeys = Object.keys(test);
    console.log("Final Result:::::",JSON.stringify(iterateObjForRemoveEmptyElem(test,myKeys)));
```

This works for me upto nth level

Answer (score 0):

```
function cleanObject(obj: object) {
  // remove all keys with undefined values in nested objects
  const cleaned = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    if (val && typeof val === 'object') {
      val = cleanObject(val);
    }
    if (val !== undefined) {
      acc[key] = val;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return cleaned;
}
const data = {
  a: 50,
  b: 90,
  c: undefined,
  d: undefined,
  e: {
    a: 90,
    b: 80,
    c: undefined,
    d: undefined,
  },
  f: {
    a: undefined,
    b: undefined,
    c: undefined,
    d: undefined,
  },
};

console.log(cleanObject(data));
```

> output => { a: 50, b: 90, e: { a: 90, b: 80 }, f: {} }

Answer (score 0):

```
// remove all falsy attributes for all layers of object

const removeFalsyProps = (body) => {
  let data = body;

  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    let value = data[key];

    // trim string type value
    if (typeof value == 'string') {
      value = value.trim();
    }

    // check value is falsy or not, then delete the property
    if (!value) {
      delete data[key];
    }

    // check value is object or not, If object then recursively call. (In JS null and array is object type)
    if (typeof value == 'object' && value != null && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      removeFalsyProps(value);
    }
  });

  return data;
};

const myOb = {
  a: 2,
  y: undefined,
  x: 0,
  s: null,
  b: '     ',
  c: { d: 8, i: '', j: { k: 1, l: '', m: { o: null, p: 'seven' } } },
  e: 'test',
  h: { a: '', b: 8, c: { d: 'de', e: 0 } },
  i: { array: ['hello'], bc: '' },
  j: 45,
  array: [],
};

console.log(removeFalsyProps(myOb));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
var testvar = {
  test1: null,
  test2: 'string',
  test3: 3,
}

function removenull(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(testvar);
console.log(removenull(testvar));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//sample Json Response
var items = {
            name: 'test',
            randomArray: [],
             randomObject: {
                id: null,
                someObject: {},
                someInternalArray: [],
                someUndefinedObject: undefined,
            },
              New name: null,
               nestedObject: [
                {
                      emp: {
                        id: null,
                    },
                   empAssets: 2,
                   joiningDate: {
                        startDate: null,
                        endDate: '2019/12/01',
                         Addresses: [],
                    },
                },
            ],
        };
       this.removeEmptyKeys(items);
        console.log('the final items ‘,items);

//Removing logic 
removeEmptyKeys(yourObject) {
        Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(key => {
            if (
                Object.prototype.toString.call(yourObject[key]) === '[object Date]' &&
                (yourObject[key].toString().length === 0 ||
                    yourObject[key].toString() === 'Invalid Date')
            ) {
                delete yourObject[key];
            } else if (yourObject[key] && typeof yourObject[key] === 'object') {
                this.removeEmptyKeysFromObject(yourObject[key]);
            } else if (yourObject[key] == null || yourObject[key] === '') {
                delete yourObject[key];
            }

            if (
                yourObject[key] &&
                typeof yourObject[key] === 'object' &&
                Object.keys(yourObject[key]).length === 0 &&
                Object.prototype.toString.call(yourObject[key]) !== '[object Date]'
            ) {
                delete yourObject[key];
            }
        });
        return yourObject;
    }
```

> Remove undefined, null, empty string , empty Arrays. Upvote if it helps.