# How to delete empty instances from an array while using a recursive clean function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

To give some background: By using Postman (the REST api tool) we are comparing XMLs to a template by converting the XMLs to JSON and compare those as Javascript objects. The comparison can handle wildcards in the values and will return a new JS object (or JSON) with only the differences. When there are no differences, I receive an empty object which is the correct state. In some cases empty values or objects are returned and we remove them from the object with a clean step.

This is how the [clean function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52368116) looks like:

```
Utils = {
  clean: function(object) {
    Object
        .entries(object)
        .forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') 
                Utils.clean(v);
            if (v && typeof v === 'object' && !Object.keys(v).length || v === null || v === undefined) 
                Array.isArray(object) ? object.splice(k, 1) :  delete object[k]; 
        });
    return object;
  }
}
```

This works fine for most cases except when we have an array with multiple the same empty object because of the `object.splice` in combination with the `foreach` [as pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24813338).

Normally, I would use a filter function, use `_.pickBy` from lodash or iterate backwards through the array, but because of the layout of the `clean` function, I can not figure out how to do that.

Can you help me to point out what I need to do to remove multiple empty items and objects from an array correctly.

Real life testcase:

```
var x = {"Document":{"CstmrDrctDbtInitn":{"GrpHdr":{},"PmtInf":{"DrctDbtTxInf":[{"PmtId":{}},{"PmtId":{}},{"PmtId":{}},{"PmtId":{}},{"PmtId":{}}]}}}};
console.log(JSON.stringify(Utils.clean(x)));
// returns {"Document":{"CstmrDrctDbtInitn":{"PmtInf":{"DrctDbtTxInf":[{},{}]}}}}
// desired result: {}
```

Other testcases:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Utils.clean({"a": [null,null,"b","c",{},{},{},{}]})));
// returns {"a":[null,"c",{},{},{}]} 
// desired: {"a":["b", "c"]}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Utils.clean({"a": [null,null,"b","c",{"d": {}},{}]})));
// returns {"a":[null,"c",{},{}]} 
// desired: {"a":["b", "c"]}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Utils.clean({ "a" : [null,null,{"d": {}, "e": [null, {}]},{}]})));
// returns {"a":[null,{}]} 
// desired: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot, and here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3rno4L7d/

**Utils Object (with extra helpers)**

```
const Utils = {
  doDelete: function(val) {
    return !Boolean(val) ||
      Utils.isEmptyObj(val) ||
      Utils.isEmptyArray(val);
  },
  isEmptyArray: function(val) {
    return Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0;
  },
  isEmptyObj: function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0 &&
      obj.constructor === Object;
  },
  hasKeys: function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length > 0;
  },
  clean: function(object) {
    Object
      .keys(object)
      .forEach(key => {
        const val = object[key];

        // If dealing with an object, clean it.
        if (val && typeof val === 'object') {
            Utils.clean(val);
        }

        // If deleteable, delete and return
        if (Utils.doDelete(val)) {
          delete object[key];
          return object;
        }

        // If array, loop over entries
        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
          let i = val.length;

          // While lets us delete from the array without affecting the loop.
          while (i--) {
            let entry = val[i];
            // If deleteable, delete from the array
            if (Utils.doDelete(entry)) {
              val.splice(i, 1)
            } else if (Utils.hasKeys(entry)) {
              // If an object, clean it
              entry = Utils.clean(entry);
              // Check to see if cleaned object is deleteable
              if (Utils.doDelete(entry)) {
                val.splice(i, 1)
              }
            }
          }
          // Once done with the array, check if deleteable
          if (Utils.doDelete(val)) {
            delete object[key];
          }
        }
      });
    return object;
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Utils.clean({"a": [null,null,"b","c",{},{},{},{}]})));
// Returns {"a":["b","c"]}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Utils.clean({"a": [null,null,"b","c",{"d": {}},{}]})));
// Returns {"a":["b","c"]}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Utils.clean({ "a" : [null,null,{"d": {}, "e": [null, {}]},{}]})));
// Returns {}
```

Comment: Thanks @lux, also for the extra effort in creating the extra helpers. As JS is not my primary language, I struggled a bit with it with all the curious undefined, empty, etc. The "real life case" didn't fully work recursively with your code, but I improved it a bit, you can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oLm5328u/). Maybe you want to add the extra line (basically just this: `if (val && typeof val === 'object') { Utils.clean(val);}` ), so the next person that wants to use it also does have that in.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Cool, I updated the answer with the extra bit. Could even check for deletion after the very first clean, similar to the `else if` in the `while` loop, but if all is working out for you, no worries.